# Django Haystack autocompletion on two (multiple) fields

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I use haystack 1.2.6 with Whoosh 2.4 and Django 1.3.
Let's say that we have the below model describing an hypothetical post.

```
Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    body = models.TextField()
```

We built our post index like this for autocompletion on body field:

```
PostIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='body')
```

Having read the haystack documentation thoroughly i cannot find if is possible to have autocompletion on both title and body fields.

So ... is it possible or ... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to do it based on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-haystack/KU7aRHzNJaU/Qhqr_AUf3I4J). You just make an EdgeNgramField for each field you want to autocomplete on in your index, then apply the autocompletion to two different search querysets and concatenate them:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Post)
sqs1 = sqs.filter(title_auto=q)
sqs2 = sqs.filter(body_auto=q)

sqs = sqs1 | sqs2
```

If you have to do extra filtering, you need to do it after the autocompletion one (at least this was the only way it worked for me).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler way, do the concatenation in the template & use `EdgeNgramField` (although doing that on the body of a post is expensive :

```
#In search_indexes.py
PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)

#In <app>\template\search\index\<app>\post_text.txt
{{ object.title }} {{object.body}}
```

Then all such queries will autocomplete on both title & body

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).autocomplete(text='hello')
```

P.S. Using Haystack 2.x